# Retrieving a slice from a multiindexed DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

I have a Pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex such as follow:

[image]

I am trying to retrieve few rows using a IndexSlice:

```
idx=pd.IndexSlice
prices.loc[idx[["2016-09-19 13:30:00":"2016-09-19 14:30:00"],"Chinese Renminbioffshore"],:]
```

But i receive error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

According to [the documentation (scroll to in:72)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html), I should be able to do that.

Anyone has a suggestion?

Here the data to recreate the dataframe:

EDIT: it seems that i cannot post the data to recreate this dataframe as it makes the proportion of the question looking like code is too great for SO... Hopefully this problem is still resolvable.

EDIT2: Maybe posting it like so would be helpful?

```
{'ID': {(Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 6211,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 37585,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 3757,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 1,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Gold'): 33824,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Henry Hub Natural Gas'): 41328,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Lean Hogs'): 9971,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Light Sweet Crude Oil'): 45089,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Live Cattle'): 21274,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'NYMEX Copper Index'): 30063,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'NYMEX Palladium Index'): 17513,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'NYMEX Platinum Index'): 26302,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Soybean Meal Futures'): 23788,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Soybean Oil Futures'): 14999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Wheat Futures'): 12485,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 6212,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 37586,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 3758,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 2,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Gold'): 33825,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Henry Hub Natural Gas'): 41329,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Lean Hogs'): 9972,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Light Sweet Crude Oil'): 45090,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Live Cattle'): 21275,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'NYMEX Copper Index'): 30064,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'NYMEX Palladium Index'): 17514,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'NYMEX Platinum Index'): 26303,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Soybean Meal Futures'): 23789,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Soybean Oil Futures'): 15000,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Wheat Futures'): 12486,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 6213,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 37587,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 3759,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 3,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Gold'): 33826,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Henry Hub Natural Gas'): 41330,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Lean Hogs'): 9973,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Light Sweet Crude Oil'): 45091,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Live Cattle'): 21276,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'NYMEX Copper Index'): 30065,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'NYMEX Palladium Index'): 17515,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'NYMEX Platinum Index'): 26304,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Soybean Meal Futures'): 23790,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Soybean Oil Futures'): 15001,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Wheat Futures'): 12487,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 6214,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 37588,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), 'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 3760,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 4,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), 'Gold'): 33827},
 'close': {(Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 128.671875,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 98.879999999999995,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 84.900000000000006,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 2132.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Gold'): 1339.4000000000001,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'Henry Hub Natural Gas'): 4.8360000000000003,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Lean Hogs'): 55.774999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'Light Sweet Crude Oil'): 49.420000000000002,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Live Cattle'): 97.224999999999994,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'NYMEX Copper Index'): 2.2149999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'NYMEX Palladium Index'): 684.29999999999995,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'NYMEX Platinum Index'): 1036.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'Soybean Meal Futures'): 336.30000000000001,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'Soybean Oil Futures'): 34.460000000000001,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Wheat Futures'): 497.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 128.609375,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 98.885000000000005,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 85.099999999999994,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 2131.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Gold'): 1339.0999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'Henry Hub Natural Gas'): 4.8179999999999996,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Lean Hogs'): 55.174999999999997,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'Light Sweet Crude Oil'): 49.719999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Live Cattle'): 97.275000000000006,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'NYMEX Copper Index'): 2.2145000000000001,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'NYMEX Palladium Index'): 692.39999999999998,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'NYMEX Platinum Index'): 1039.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Soybean Meal Futures'): 335.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Soybean Oil Futures'): 34.5,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Wheat Futures'): 494.25,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 128.609375,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 98.885000000000005,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'),
   'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 85.099999999999994,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 2128.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Gold'): 1338.2,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'),
   'Henry Hub Natural Gas'): 4.8179999999999996,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Lean Hogs'): 55.024999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'),
   'Light Sweet Crude Oil'): 49.689999999999998,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Live Cattle'): 97.125,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'NYMEX Copper Index'): 2.2145000000000001,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'),
   'NYMEX Palladium Index'): 688.79999999999995,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'NYMEX Platinum Index'): 1040.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'),
   'Soybean Meal Futures'): 333.19999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'),
   'Soybean Oil Futures'): 34.530000000000001,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Wheat Futures'): 491.25,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 128.640625,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 98.885000000000005,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'),
   'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 85.099999999999994,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 2129.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), 'Gold'): 1338.2},
 'high': {(Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 128.703125,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 98.879999999999995,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 84.900000000000006,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 2133.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Gold'): 1341.2,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'Henry Hub Natural Gas'): 4.8529999999999998,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Lean Hogs'): 56.149999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Light Sweet Crude Oil'): 49.5,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Live Cattle'): 97.724999999999994,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'NYMEX Copper Index'): 2.2200000000000002,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'NYMEX Palladium Index'): 684.79999999999995,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'NYMEX Platinum Index'): 1039.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'Soybean Meal Futures'): 339.30000000000001,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'Soybean Oil Futures'): 34.469999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Wheat Futures'): 498.25,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 128.71875,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 98.885000000000005,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 85.099999999999994,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 2134.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Gold'): 1340.2,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'Henry Hub Natural Gas'): 4.8410000000000002,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Lean Hogs'): 55.774999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'Light Sweet Crude Oil'): 49.920000000000002,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Live Cattle'): 97.400000000000006,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'NYMEX Copper Index'): 2.2164999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'NYMEX Palladium Index'): 693.75,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'NYMEX Platinum Index'): 1041.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Soybean Meal Futures'): 336.5,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'Soybean Oil Futures'): 34.609999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Wheat Futures'): 497.25,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 128.640625,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 98.885000000000005,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'),
   'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 85.099999999999994,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 2131.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Gold'): 1339.7,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'),
   'Henry Hub Natural Gas'): 4.8220000000000001,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Lean Hogs'): 55.375,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'),
   'Light Sweet Crude Oil'): 49.880000000000003,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Live Cattle'): 97.200000000000003,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'NYMEX Copper Index'): 2.2155,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'),
   'NYMEX Palladium Index'): 692.79999999999995,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'NYMEX Platinum Index'): 1041.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Soybean Meal Futures'): 335.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Soybean Oil Futures'): 34.57,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Wheat Futures'): 494.5,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 128.65625,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 98.885000000000005,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'),
   'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 85.099999999999994,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 2130.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), 'Gold'): 1338.8},
 'low': {(Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 128.625,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 98.879999999999995,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 84.900000000000006,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 2125.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Gold'): 1338.7,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'Henry Hub Natural Gas'): 4.8029999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Lean Hogs'): 55.100000000000001,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'Light Sweet Crude Oil'): 49.039999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Live Cattle'): 96.900000000000006,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'NYMEX Copper Index'): 2.2134999999999998,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'NYMEX Palladium Index'): 681.79999999999995,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'NYMEX Platinum Index'): 1034.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'Soybean Meal Futures'): 336.10000000000002,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'Soybean Oil Futures'): 34.270000000000003,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Wheat Futures'): 493.25,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 128.59375,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 98.879999999999995,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 85.099999999999994,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 2130.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Gold'): 1338.5999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'Henry Hub Natural Gas'): 4.8129999999999997,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Lean Hogs'): 55.125,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'Light Sweet Crude Oil'): 49.240000000000002,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Live Cattle'): 96.849999999999994,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'NYMEX Copper Index'): 2.2094999999999998,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'NYMEX Palladium Index'): 683.85000000000002,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'NYMEX Platinum Index'): 1036.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'Soybean Meal Futures'): 334.69999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'Soybean Oil Futures'): 34.450000000000003,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Wheat Futures'): 494.25,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 128.546875,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 98.885000000000005,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'),
   'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 85.099999999999994,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 2127.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Gold'): 1337.5999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'),
   'Henry Hub Natural Gas'): 4.8019999999999996,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Lean Hogs'): 54.875,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'),
   'Light Sweet Crude Oil'): 49.560000000000002,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Live Cattle'): 96.799999999999997,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'NYMEX Copper Index'): 2.2134999999999998,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'),
   'NYMEX Palladium Index'): 688.60000000000002,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'NYMEX Platinum Index'): 1039.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Soybean Meal Futures'): 333.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'),
   'Soybean Oil Futures'): 34.479999999999997,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Wheat Futures'): 490.25,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 128.59375,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 98.885000000000005,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'),
   'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 85.099999999999994,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 2127.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), 'Gold'): 1337.7},
 'open': {(Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 128.6875,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 98.879999999999995,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 84.900000000000006,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 2126.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Gold'): 1341.2,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'Henry Hub Natural Gas'): 4.8129999999999997,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Lean Hogs'): 55.649999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'Light Sweet Crude Oil'): 49.100000000000001,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Live Cattle'): 97.599999999999994,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'NYMEX Copper Index'): 2.2170000000000001,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'NYMEX Palladium Index'): 681.79999999999995,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'NYMEX Platinum Index'): 1039.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'Soybean Meal Futures'): 337.69999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   'Soybean Oil Futures'): 34.299999999999997,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Wheat Futures'): 495.75,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 128.671875,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 98.879999999999995,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 85.099999999999994,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 2132.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Gold'): 1339.3,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'Henry Hub Natural Gas'): 4.8380000000000001,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Lean Hogs'): 55.774999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'Light Sweet Crude Oil'): 49.409999999999997,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Live Cattle'): 97.200000000000003,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'NYMEX Copper Index'): 2.2149999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'NYMEX Palladium Index'): 684.35000000000002,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'NYMEX Platinum Index'): 1037.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'Soybean Meal Futures'): 336.30000000000001,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'),
   'Soybean Oil Futures'): 34.469999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Wheat Futures'): 497.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 128.609375,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 98.885000000000005,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'),
   'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 85.099999999999994,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 2131.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Gold'): 1339.0999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'),
   'Henry Hub Natural Gas'): 4.8179999999999996,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Lean Hogs'): 55.174999999999997,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'),
   'Light Sweet Crude Oil'): 49.719999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Live Cattle'): 97.200000000000003,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'NYMEX Copper Index'): 2.2149999999999999,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'NYMEX Palladium Index'): 691.25,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'NYMEX Platinum Index'): 1039.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'),
   'Soybean Meal Futures'): 334.89999999999998,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Soybean Oil Futures'): 34.5,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Wheat Futures'): 494.25,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 128.609375,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 98.885000000000005,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'),
   'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 85.099999999999994,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 2128.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), 'Gold'): 1338.2},
 'volume': {(Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'),
   '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 30941.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 251.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 0.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 164450.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Gold'): 6173.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Henry Hub Natural Gas'): 8462.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Lean Hogs'): 1489.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Light Sweet Crude Oil'): 30803.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Live Cattle'): 2970.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'NYMEX Copper Index'): 3066.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'NYMEX Palladium Index'): 373.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'NYMEX Platinum Index'): 1014.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Soybean Meal Futures'): 4978.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Soybean Oil Futures'): 8493.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 13:30:00'), 'Wheat Futures'): 7462.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 40382.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 526.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 1250.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 117841.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Gold'): 4891.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Henry Hub Natural Gas'): 3945.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Lean Hogs'): 729.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Light Sweet Crude Oil'): 44921.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Live Cattle'): 1380.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'NYMEX Copper Index'): 3076.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'NYMEX Palladium Index'): 1062.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'NYMEX Platinum Index'): 624.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Soybean Meal Futures'): 3007.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Soybean Oil Futures'): 6114.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:00:00'), 'Wheat Futures'): 3592.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 32360.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 0.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 0.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 76527.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Gold'): 3831.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Henry Hub Natural Gas'): 4526.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Lean Hogs'): 406.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Light Sweet Crude Oil'): 27306.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Live Cattle'): 735.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'NYMEX Copper Index'): 1394.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'NYMEX Palladium Index'): 235.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'NYMEX Platinum Index'): 419.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Soybean Meal Futures'): 3348.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Soybean Oil Futures'): 3559.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 14:30:00'), 'Wheat Futures'): 4125.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), '10 Year US Treasury Note'): 23938.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), '30 Day Fed Funds'): 0.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), 'Bloomberg Commodity Index'): 30.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), 'E-mini S&P 500'): 68578.0,
  (Timestamp('2016-09-19 15:00:00'), 'Gold'): 2537.0}}
```

Comment: Try to post it anyway.  It may be a simple formatting issue.  Either way, I don't want to create that nasty looking dataframe by hand.  Worst case scenario, I edit your question and see/copy your data.  Best case is that it looks great.  Middle case is that someone edits your question and fixes formatting for you.

Comment: @piRSquared No I cannot post it.. I receive an error message from SO that the message has too much code.

Comment: Then it's on you to reduce the code to produce a minimal example that can recreate your problem.  You don't have to do anything I say.  But I'd be willing to bet that if you did that, someone would answer your question in very short order.  Someone still might.

Comment: Can you instead do `df.head(20).to_dict()` and post the output here? It's much easier to construct that way, than working with that data dump.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes thats what i did to begin with, but couldnt post it. However as an edit it did work. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by passing  tuple of `(idx[...], your_value)` as the first argument to `loc`.

```
prices.loc[(idx["2016-09-19 13:30:00":"2016-09-19 14:30:00"], xxx), :]
```

---

Example:

```
prices.loc[(idx["2016-09-19 13:30:00":"2016-09-19 14:30:00"], 'Gold'), :]

                             ID   close    high     low    open  volume
2016-09-19 13:30:00 Gold  33824  1339.4  1341.2  1338.7  1341.2  6173.0
2016-09-19 14:00:00 Gold  33825  1339.1  1340.2  1338.6  1339.3  4891.0
2016-09-19 14:30:00 Gold  33826  1338.2  1339.7  1337.6  1339.1  3831.0
```

Comment: Yes it works, thx. Really appreciate that you guys take the time to reply. BTW is there anyway this is shown in the documentation?

Comment: @jimbasquiat Haha you’d be hard pressed to find this in the docs. Experimentation really, that’s all it is.